# Writing additional \section commands

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, formatting, line-breaking

My company has a Word document with lots of styles based on the basic headings. I need to create LaTeX equivalents and am struggling with how to do so because I need to do more than just redefine `\chapter`, `\section`, etc.

As a simple example, there are three styles based on (Word's) Heading 2 style. All three have some common properties: they are Arial 13pt bold, with 10 pts vertical space before, keep with next paragraph properties (so that line can't be the last line on a page), and a level 2 table of contents entry.

From there, the styles diverge: there's a style that uses a blue color for the font, a second style that autonumbers (so it counts Activity 1, Activity 2, etc), and a third that has no numbering or color changes.

What is the best way to create these styles? Ideally I'd like to create commands so I can say `\activity` or whatever for any of the three.

Comment: Sounds like your company has developed some specialized templates for headers. Must the output created by the templates be preserved exactly?

Comment: I'm confused.  Does this mean that there are three separate types of level 2 heading styles?  Are there separate types of all levels of heading?  How many levels of headings are there?

Comment: @dgoodmaniii There are three different types of headings, all of which show up at level 2 within Word's table of contents.

Comment: Are they all number together, or do they maintain separate numbering schemes?

Comment: @Mico there is some flexibility but not much. For more context, I've been given the authority to attempt to implement the existing templates in LaTeX so we can do better version control of the documents than with Microsoft Word files. But, my solution needs to be passably similar to our existing documents.

Comment: @dgoodmaniii The only one that has a numbering scheme is activities, but that is separate from any other numbering in the document (chapters, ordered lists, etc.)

Comment: What have you got so far? Do you have code which at least produces something roughly the way it needs to look? (Even if it doesn't do so via the kind of commands you need?) What engine are you using? (Does it have to be Arial or will a look-alike do?) Does it have to look like Word generally? That is, does it need to look... well... crappy? I don't mean any offence, by the way. This is a serious question. I've done this myself and I can probably find the package I used if you need that. (It turns off most of the stuff which makes LaTeX documents look good. It's a great package.)

Comment: @Colin:  Okay, I understand now.  Does the styling continue to the TOC, or only in the text?

Answer (score 3):

Here's something that (probably) does what you want.  It doesn't use Arial, because I don't have it and don't like it, but substitutes Latin Modern Sans. You type `\newsection` with two arguments; the first says which type of `\newsection` it is, and the second is the section name.  `a` is one type (no number, blue), `b` is another (no number, still black, no font change), and anything else will make the third (numbered, sans serif).  Each prints itself as a section-level heading in the TOC.  (I assume that `section` is your second-level heading; if that's not true [say, if you're using the `article` class], you would need to change `section` to `subsection` in the `\addcontentsline` directives.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcounter{newsect}
\setcounter{newsect}{0}
\makeatletter%
\def\newsection#1#2{%
    \ifstrequal{#1}{a}{%
        \fontsize{13pt}{15pt}\selectfont%
        \hbox to\linewidth{\textcolor{blue}{\textsf{#2}}\hfil}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
    }{\ifstrequal{#1}{b}{%
        \fontsize{13pt}{15pt}\selectfont%
        \hbox to\linewidth{#2\hfil}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
    }{%
        \stepcounter{newsect}%
        \fontsize{13pt}{15pt}\selectfont%
        \hbox to\linewidth{%
            \hbox to2em{\thenewsect\hfil}\textsf{#2}%
            \hfil%
        }%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{%
          \hbox to2em{\thenewsect\hfil}#2}%
    }}%
    \penalty10000%
}%
\makeatother%
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newsection{a}{Lorem}
\newsection{b}{Ipsum}
\newsection{c}{Loquitur}
\newsection{c}{whatever}
\newsection{b}{does}
\newsection{a}{this}
\newsection{c}{work?}
\end{document}
```

Will give you this:

[image: Weird Section Headings]

A couple of caveats here:  section titles will look bad if more than one line (fixable, but I'm putting this together on the fly here).  The color and font changes do *not* carry into the TOC here, but that's also easily fixed.  I believe that `\penalty10000` will prevent any page breaks in the space following one of these headings, as requested, no matter how terrible it might look; `\parskip` will probably expand to an unacceptable degree in the close cases to make up for one of these headings skipping to the next page.  Ideally, it would simply leave empty space at the bottom of the page when this happens; this board has ways to do that, but I don't have time to look them up right now.

Finally, this looks terrible, and I pity you having to reproduce it.  Maybe a little experience with LaTeX will lead your employers to some better style choices.

Comment: When I tried to reproduce this, it doesn't seem to restore the font back to normal for the following paragraph, and the leading/trailing vertical space is missing. But this is close!

Answer (score 2):

The code below gives us the following output:

[image: colinNewSectioncommands]

```
% arara: xelatex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\DeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-10pt,afterskip=10pt,
    font={\color{blue!40!black}\fontspec{Arial}\normalfont},
    style=section,
    level=1,
    tocindent=2em,
    tocnumwidth=2em,
    indent=0pt
]{activityB}% B, as in blue
\DeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-10pt,afterskip=10pt,
    font={\fontspec{Arial}\normalfont},
%   counterwithin=chapter,
    style=section,
    level=1,
    tocindent=1em,
    tocnumwidth=2em,
    indent=0pt
]{activity}
\renewcommand{\blindtext}{This is just a simple test}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{pogo penguin}
\blindtext
\section{walzing Wombat}
\blindtext
\activity{samba snake}
\blindtext
\activity*{salsa squirrel}
\blindtext
\activityB{Lambada leguan}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

The example needs to be run with XeLaTeX, to easily use Arial. It uses pretty new features of KOMA-script, so an up to date version is required.

It might be a better idea though, to define new floating environments and have the activities in a list of their own. But without knowing the actual use case, it is hard to know.

Comment: Can you expand on the "floating environments" idea?

Comment: @philosophyguy If the *activities* are rather short sections (third or half of a page),  afloating box might be a better idea, and an extra list with just the different activies using the `caption` command (or a different command, but a similar mechanism). It really depends on the use case.